# How to insert local time into inserted_at and updated_at columns of mysql DB with Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm in Japan. I would like to insert local time into inserted_at and updated_at columns. Currently the columns inserted UTC time.

Are there suitable place set the local time in Phoenix framework or Ecto setting?

- Elixir 1.6
- Phoenix 1.3
- MySQL 5.5

Comment: Why not just display the time in your prefered timezone? Saving times in UTC is basically a standard.

Comment: @JustinWood makes a good point. I think the best thing to do is persist time in UTC (default) and then convert it for display.

Comment: Yes i should be. But where is the best place to make function which include converting time zones for whole application? I don’t think to convert time zone for every display is good way.